# I get an error when saving data from File Manager in Realm

Tags: realm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hDId.png)

I get an error when saving data from File Manager in Realm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Please include your code so we know what's crashing. For future reference, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)